# How can I convert Python list to column vector?

Tags: python, matlab

I'm using the fitdist method from MATLAB in Python where x is:
[image]

I tried different approaches to work on this and they all give the same error:

```
eng.fitdist(eng.cell2mat(list(x)), 'stable')
eng.fitdist(matlab.double(list(x)), 'stable')
eng.fitdist(list(x), 'stable')
```

All of these give me this error:

```
MatlabExecutionError:  
        File C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2020b\toolbox\stats\stats\fitdist.m, line 126, in fitdist X must be a numeric column vector.
```

Any idea how to get out of it? How do I convert my list to a column vector that works with MATLAB?
I am using MATLAB R2020b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the `size` argument of `matlab.double` for creating a column vector.

Column vector in MATLAB is equivalent to 2D matrix with second dimension size equals 1.
For example: A Matrix with size `[5, 1]` is a column vector with 5 columns.

According to the documentation, [MATLAB Arrays as Python Variables](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/matlab-arrays-as-python-variables.html):
`matlab.double` has an optional `size` argument:

> matlab.double(initializer=None, **size**=None, is_complex=False)

You can set `size` argument to `(x.size, 1)` for creating a column vector.

The following syntax works (assuming x is a NumPy array):

```
eng.fitdist(matlab.double(list(x), (x.size, 1)), 'stable')
```

The following syntax also works:

```
eng.fitdist(matlab.double(list(x), (len(list(x)), 1)), 'stable')
```

---

The following code was used for testing:

```python
import numpy as np
import matlab
import matlab.engine
eng = matlab.engine.start_matlab()

x = np.array([176.0, 163.0, 131.0, 133.0, 119.0, 142.0, 142.0, 180.0, 183.0, 132.0, 128.0, 137.0, 174.0])

eng.fitdist(matlab.double(list(x), (x.size, 1)), 'stable')
```

---

### Update:

Reading the results of `fitdist` in Python:

Reading the results is challenging, because `fitdist` returns an object of type `'prob.StableDistribution'`.
It would be easer to get the result as an array.
My suggestion is creating a MATLAB "wrapper function" that returns an array.

Example:

MATALB code file `my_fitdist.m`:

```matlab
function y = my_fitdist(x)
if (size(x, 1) == 1), x = x.';end % Make sure input is a column array.
s = fitdist(x, 'stable');
y = [s.alpha, s.beta, s.gam, s.delta]; % Put the output of fitdist in an array
```

Python code:

```python
import numpy as np
import matlab
import matlab.engine
eng = matlab.engine.start_matlab()

x = np.array([176.0, 163.0, 131.0, 133.0, 119.0, 142.0, 142.0, 180.0, 183.0, 132.0, 128.0, 137.0, 174.0])

y = eng.my_fitdist(matlab.double(list(x))) # Execute the wrapper function "my_fitdist"
```

There could be a better solution, but am not experienced with MATLAB Engine.

Comment: Thank you! This definitely solved my problem. Just wondering if you know how I can access the result in Python? I'm trying to see the computed alpha but I'm not sure how. I'm new to MATLAB :)

Comment: Using a MATLAB "wrapper function" is a possible solution (I updated the post).